# Intellij does not recognize Haxe SDK

Tags: intellij-idea, sdk, haxe

I would like to work with haxe on intellij but it seems that is not able to recognize the haxe sdk, when i try to create a new project, intellij ask me to point the project sdk and i don't really know what to do.

i tryed to point the sdk to the haxe folder but an error message appear saying: `The selected directory is not a valid home for Haxe toolkit`

[image]
Intellij IDEA version: 13.1
Anyone can help?
Thanks

Comment: resolved by myself, intellij was asking for the bin folder. You can find it on `/usr/bin/` (under ubuntu distibutions)

Comment: Yes. I was confused by this as well. It is actually asking for the location of the haxe binary. `which haxe` revealed `/usr/bin/haxe` for me on ubuntu. I typed in that path and it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

The configuration needs the directory the haxe binary is installed to. If running `which haxe` gives you `/usr/bin/haxe` you should set `/usr/bin` as the haxe toolkit directory.

Comment: When you solve a problem yourself, add an answer instead of commenting on the question. This makes it clear the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know where exactly it is in linux, under which /usr/bin folder but in Windows 8 in C:\ folder,  you'll see a haxetoolkit folder and in it there will be the haxe folder, which is the one it asks for!